# PHP - Replace li of one array with another

Tags: php, html, arrays

I am trying to create a tree structure using `ul` and `li`. I need to always show a tree structure no matter whether we have values in database or not. So I created a function and made a tree structure. Now I want to replace `li` data when we have values for those nodes in database. Here is code that is produced by my arrays.

```
<li><a href="#">1</a>
        <ul><li><a href="#">2</a>
                <ul><li><a href="#">2.1</a>
                        <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">2.1.1</a>                 
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">2.1.2</a>   
                                </li>               
                        </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                        <a href="#">2.2</a>
                        <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">2.2.1</a>                    
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">2.2.2</a>     
                                </li>                   
                        </ul>
                </li></ul>
                </li>
        </ul>
</li>
```

This is the basic structure and I want to replace nodes like `2.1, 2.1.1,2.2.2` when we have values in another array which is giving output like

```
<li>
        <a>
                <div class="card">
                        <div class="thumb">grey</div>
                        <div class="id">157</div>
                        <div class="username">okamikid1</div>
                </div>
        </a>
        <ul>
                <li><a><div class="card">
                        <div class="thumb">red</div>
                        <div class="id">158</div>
                        <div class="username">okamikid1</div>
                </div>
        </a>
        <ul></ul></li></ul>
</li>
```

Basically I have two arrays,both arrays have `li` in it. I want to replace `li` of first array with second array and want to keep other values of second array those don't exist in first array.

Here is array structure of first array in json form, so that you can see structure more clearly.

```
{"157":{"id":"157","username":"okamikid1","parent_id":null,"children":[{"id":"158","parent_id":"157","username":"okamikid1","children":[]},{"id":"160","parent_id":"157","username":"okamikid2","children":[]}]}}
```

Comment: _“So basically i want to replace li of one array with li of another array.”_ - and yet, you have not even shown any arrays yet … Show code, show what you tried.

Comment: Hi @CBroe. The output you seeing above is what I'm getting from array.

Comment: Since you haven't actually shown the underlying database structure, the PHP code that generates the arrays, or this output from them, we haven't really got enough to go on here; *technically* the answer could be *"well, delete the first HTML block and replace it with the second** - do you see the problem we'd have trying to answer this?

Comment: I am generating `li` by using various functions, posting those functions here is not possible. Basically you can get an idea from the question itself. I have two arrays,both arrays have `li`. I want to replace `li` of first array in second array and want to keep other values those don't exist in first array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments, I assume you want to show a tree structure with data from the database. Also, you want to have the `node` exists in the tree structure even if the value is not present in the database.

I would suggest the following workaround.

Suppose you have two arrays like

```
$placeholders = [
    1 => [
        '1.1' => '1.1',
        '1.2' => '1.2',
        '1.3' => '1.3',
    ],
    2 => [
        '2.1' => '2.1',
        '2.2' => '2.2',
        '2.3' => '2.3',
    ],
    3 => [
        '3.1' => '3.1',
        '3.2' => '3.2',
        '3.3' => '3.3',
    ]
];
```

The `$placeholders` array defines the tree structure.

Now you have some function to fetch data from the database in the following format.

```
$data = [
    1 => [
        '1.1' => 'Node 1.1',
        '1.2' => 'Node 1.2',
        '1.3' => 'Node 1.3',
    ],
    2 => [
        '2.1' => 'Node 2.1',
        '2.2' => 'Node 2.2',
        '2.3' => 'Node 2.3',
    ]
];
```

Now, use the [array_replace_recursive](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace-recursive.php) function to replace the placeholders with actual values from the database.

```
$data = array_replace_recursive($placeholders, $data);
```

Then print the tree structure like:

```
foreach ($data as $base => $nodes)
{
    echo "<ul>";
    echo "<li>{$base}</li>";
    echo "<ul>";
    foreach ($nodes as $node) {
        echo "<li>{$node}</li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
    echo "</ul>";
}
```

Comment: Hey @invalid bot, can we do something directly with `li`? I mean can we directly replace `li` in array. I have used a function to create ul li from array items.

Comment: It is impossible to answer your question without knowing the array structure. Post the array structure.

Comment: added array structure in question. Please check. I am creating ul li from this structure.

Comment: After digging deeper, I used your example as reference and it works. Thanks a lot dude.